# In Visual Studio 2013 unable to migrate ASP Web Application to Azure Web Role - where is the 'Add Windows Azure Deployment Project' option?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2013

In a new solution in VS2013, I am following the instructions on [migrating an ASP Web Application to an Azure Web Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420322.aspx#EnableApp).

I created a new ASP.Net Web Application project in my solution. Right-clicking on the project does not render the option *Add Windows Azure Deployment Project*, and am unable to locate a VS2013-related fix.

I added a new Azure Cloud Service/WebRole project to the solution, and am wondering if I can just take guts from the first Web App and move them to the Web Role (I didn't see any new name spaces in the classes I looked at)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution should contain both the Azure Cloud Service/WebRole project and the ASP.Net Web Application project.  Then in the Azure Cloud Service/WebRole project, right-click on the "Roles" folder >> Add >> Web Role Project in solution.

Comment: Ah there we go... then selected my ASP.Net Web Application project.  Thank you.